# Spark invalidate session at restart

Tags: java, session, jetty, spark-java

I have a problem with sparkjava, when i restart the webserver, all the sessions created before the restart are invalidate (or deleted, do not know). How i can prevent that? It's a very annoying issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should persist sessions info in database like Redis, on keep in memory service like memcached.

This way you can also serve users using many computing point under a load balancer like nginx.